# *ngIf not showing element when data changes

Tags: angular

So I have found similar questions and tried the solutions like a manual change detection but I just can't get this to work.

I have an navegation bar element in a component (app.component.ts) that I want to show when a parameter(_isSessionActive:boolean) from another component (login.component.ts) changes from true to false when im in that component view (login.component.html). This doesn't happen. I may be doing something wrong but I have a similar project that works with a similar structure and I cant understand why. I've simplified the code all I could. Thanks in advance.

**app.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar">
<li><a href="#" *ngIf="loginComponent._isSessionActive==true" routerLink="/admin">Admin</a></li>
</nav>


 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  moduleId:module.id, 
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `app.component.html`,
  providers:[UserService,LoginComponent]   
})
export class AppComponent { 

  constructor(private loginComponent:LoginComponent) {

  }


}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<button  (click)="isSessionActiveTrue()">true</button>
<button  (click)="isSessionActiveFalse()">false</button>
<button  (click)="isSessionActiveCheck()">check</button>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class LoginComponent {


_isSessionActive: boolean = false;

constructor(private router: Router) {

}

 isSessionActiveTrue(){
this._isSessionActive=true;
 }

 isSessionActiveFalse(){
this._isSessionActive=false;
 }

 isSessionActiveCheck(){
console.log(this._isSessionActive);
 }

 }
```

Comment: What are you calling a service `xxxComponent`?

Comment: Yes, should be named service, is just a name, doesn't really bother me right now, I had plans to change it later on :)

Comment: What do you get for `<div>{{loginComponent._isSessionActive}}</div>`?

Comment: Weird names are confusing in questions - just sayin ;-)

Comment: Why is there a `login.component.html` when it's actually a service? Services don't have templates.

Comment: I know Günter and you are right, my fault, I really didn't think about it when posting

Comment: I just wanted to be able to share that parameter with the other component, didnt know how to do it

Comment: So the default value is `false` therefore `*ngIf="..."` doesn't show anything. and `(click)="isSessionActiveTrue()"` might do whatever (unclear from your question) and won't make `_isSessionActive` `true`, therefore `*ngIf="..."` still won't show anything. Conclusion: The buttons and what a click does, is not related to `*ngIf`

Comment: For components that are not parent-children use a shared service https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: (click)="isSessionActiveTrue() should set _isSessionActive = true

Comment: Don't you need to use `@ViewChild(LoginComponent) login: LoginComponent;`?

Comment: `LoginComponent` is either a component or a service. If you add `@Injectable()` and add it to `providers: []` it's a services. If it's a service it can't have a template, therefore `<button (click)="...">` is unrelated to `LoginComponent`. If `LoginComponent` is actually a component, it should have a `@Component()` decorator and can't be a service.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer so it will throw if the class has an `@Component(...)` decorator applied? `@Injectable()` is completely optional so it won't throw for that.

Comment: At first you need to make clear if `LoginComponent` is a component or a service. Currently in your question this is as unclear as it can get ;-)

Comment: Ok Im going to try to restructure my code...

Comment: I have the suspicion that you're using `LoginComponent` as component and service at the same time. This is theoretically possible, but in 99.999% of all cases a very bad idea. In your case the `(click)"..."` will update `_isSessionActive` on a different instance of `LoginComponent` than the one injected to `AppComponent`

Comment: Ye, that's basically what I was doing. Im new to angular 2, didn't know that shouldn't be done. I'll try to find another way around

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks for the shared service link, got to clarify me many things. I finally remade the whole and is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from extremely confusing names why are you doing

```
 *ngIf="loginComponent._isSessionActive==true"
```

when

```
*ngIf="loginComponent._isSessionActive"
```

is just fine?